# JavaFX with Apache POI FindException error

Tags: java

I have a JavaFX project that worked perfectly.

But I want to use Apache POI in the project and now I have encountered problems.

First of all I needed to add `requires org.apache.poi.poi` in the module-info.java file.

But when running i get this error message.

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.slf4j not found, required by org.apache.poi.poi
```

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Did you try [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=module+org.slf4j+not+found+required+by+org.apache.poi.poi&client=firefox-b-d&ei=zhiYYJerKrvqxgOwjIrwBQ&oq=module+org.slf4j&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIFCAAQsAMyBQgAELADMgcIABCwAxAeMgkIABCwAxAIEB4yCQgAELADEAgQHjIJCAAQsAMQCBAeUABYAGDoiAFoAXAAeACAAXWIAXWSAQMwLjGYAQCqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEGwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) for the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I installed `Apache POI 5.0.0`:

[image]

To fix the issue, I rolled back to version `4.1.2`, and everything worked as expected. You can get the Binary files from [here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/poi/release/bin/), or the Source files from [here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/poi/release/src/). Equally, you could get it through the Maven repository.

Note. you'll need to update your `module-info.java` to the following:

```
requires poi;
requires poi.ooxml;
requires poi.ooxml.schemas;
```

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: When I try this solution, I now get 'Module poi.ooxml not found'